# Python string contains byte array

Tags: python, python-bytearray

I've experimented with the Python module named `array` a bit. It has got a way to encode arrays to strings.

```python
>>>from array import array
>>>a=[1,2,3]
>>>a=array('B',a)
>>>print(a)
array('B',[1,2,3])
>>>print(a.tostring())
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>>str(a.tostring())
"b'\x01\x02\x03'"
```

I want to save the `.tostring()` version of the array into a file, but the `open().write()` only accepts strings.

Is there a way to decode this string to a byte-array?

I want to use it for OpenGL arrays (`glBufferData` accepts the byte-arrays)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VineetKumarDoshi
Notice that str(a) & a.tostring() isn't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to encode/decode the array any further. You can write the bytes returned by `tostring()` into a file using the `'wb'` mode:

```
from array import array
a = array('B', [1, 2, 3])
with open(path, 'wb') as byte_file:
    byte_file.write(a.tostring())
```

You can also read bytes from a file using the `'rb'` mode:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as byte_file:
    a = array('B', byte_file.readline())
```

This will load the stored array from the file and save it into the variable `a`:

```
>>> print(a)
array('B', [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
>>> open('foo.txt','wb').write(a.tostring())
```